# how to show html result view in wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

i want to show html code in textarea and then user can clink view resut.

[image]

code:

```
<textarea id="html" cols="50" rows="10">&lt;html&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
This text will appear on your webpage.
&lt;/p&gt; 
&lt;!--
the text within these comment tags will not appear on the web page
--&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</textarea>

<div>
<button onclick="view()">View Results</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function view()
{
    var result = window.open("", "", "height=400,left=" + ((screen.width) ? (screen.width-400)/2 : 0) + ",top=" + ((screen.height) ? (screen.height-400)/2 : 0) + ",width=400");

    var tmp = result.document;
    tmp.write(document.getElementById('html').value);
    tmp.close();

    return false;
}
</script>
```

i try post it on wordpress post, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress strips out HTML tags by default. An easy way to begin with would be to use a plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-coder/ to paste your code into and then use a shortcode to run it. Ideally you want to look into building your own plugins, but as a quick fix this will be ideal for you :)

Comment: No problem, please mark as the answer and mark as solved :) Thanks